# Display an array document in Angular App as table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Im currently working on an Angular App and have gotten to a problem i can't find any solution for.

I have this Schema:

```
const ContentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
subject: String,
customer: String,
task: String,
date: Date,
inCharge: String,
comment: [String] })
```

This method in my Angular-App retrieves the Content on init of the Component.

```
  this.contentServ.getContent()
      .subscribe(data => this.contents  = data as mycontent[])
```

This is how my service is accessing the api

```
getContent(): Observable<mycontent[]> {
    return this.http.get<mycontent[]>('/api/retrieveContent')
  }
```

And this is how im displaying it

```
 <tr *ngFor="let content of contents">
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="contentAction" id="{{content._id}}"></th>      
      <th>{{content.subject}}</th>
      <th>{{content.customer}}</th>
      <th>{{content.task}}</th>
      <th>{{content.date | date : "dd.MM.yyyy" }}</th>
      <th>{{content.inCharge}}</th>
      <th>{{content.comment}}</th>
    </tr>
```

When i do this, my comments get displayed but they are displayed as they get passed by the JS from the DB:

```
{ comment: [ 'This is my first comment', 'i can now add another one' ],
    _id: 5bd0221100acd00f5bf8800d,
    subject: 'Application Development',
    customer: 'myCustomer',
    task: 'myTask',
    date: 2018-10-15T00:00:00.000Z,
    inCharge: 'myOfficial',
    __v: 0 }
```

Now the problem is, that {{content.comment}} is an array i cant access by doing this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let content of contents, let i = index">
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="contentAction" id="{{content._id}}"></th>      
      <th>{{content.subject}}</th>
      <th>{{content.customer}}</th>
      <th>{{content.task}}</th>
      <th>{{content.date | date : "dd.MM.yyyy" }}</th>
      <th>{{content.inCharge}}</th>
      <th>{{content.comment[i]}}</th>
    </tr>
```

also tried this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let content of contents">
      <th><input type="checkbox" name="contentAction" id="{{content._id}}"></th>      
      <th>{{content.subject}}</th>
      <th>{{content.customer}}</th>
      <th>{{content.task}}</th>
      <th>{{content.date | date : "dd.MM.yyyy" }}</th>
      <th>{{content.inCharge}}</th>
      <th><ul *ngFor="let content.comment of content.comments, let i = index><li>{{content.comment[i]}}</li></th>
    </tr>
```

I even tried doing this:

```
<th id="displayComments"></th>
```

and doing

```
 document.getElementById("displayComments").innerHTML = {{this.contents.comment}}.join(" <br> ");
```

But nothing of this seems to work as inteded.

My goal is to get an output in my table where i have something like

```
  <tr *ngFor="let content of contents">
          <th><input type="checkbox" name="contentAction" id="{{content._id}}"></th>
          <th>{{content.subject}}</th>
          <th>{{content.customer}}</th>
          <th>{{content.task}}</th>
          <th>{{content.date | date : "dd.MM.yyyy" }}</th>
          <th>{{content.inCharge}}</th>
          <th><ul>
<li>My Comment nr. 1</li>
<li>My Comment nr. 2</li>
</ul></th>
        </tr>
```

I hope some of you guys may be able to help me with my problem.

If you need further information of my code, I'll give it to you as fast as I can.

Comment: `let content.comment of content.comments` you cannot `let` something like that, let is used to create or ask angular to create a local variable for each iteration. It can be something like `let mycomment of content.comments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if possible create a stackblitz or plunkr demo.

And try changing,

```
<th><ul *ngFor="let content.comment of content.comments, let i = index><li>{{content.comment[i]}}</li></th>
</tr>
```

to this,

```
<th><ul *ngFor="let comment of content.comments"><li>{{comment}}</li></th>
</tr>
```

It may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You could build a custom component which takes the comments array as an input and inside that component, you could use `*ngFor` over that array to output the markup that you want.